# Will a mismatch between my name the papers I authored and the name in my official documents cause trouble in getting hired?

Tags: paper-submission, authorship, arxiv, preprint, personal-name

When I submitted my first article to arXiv, in the article I mentioned my full name, which is just 'Afham' (I do not know whether it is not allowed to mention such personal information in a question, sorry if it is not). Because of this, my name is not listed as a co-author in the google scholar entry of the paper and neither is the paper listed under my google scholar page.

Do people use unofficial names while submitting papers and can this lead to career related consequences in the future?

Comment: Are there any other names used in your culture, like a patronymic?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yes, for the most part. It does not answer the last question - will it have career-related consequences. Like would potential employers/universities make an issue when all the papers are with one name and official records show another name?

Yes, I unofficially use my father's name as my last name, but it is not present in the official certificates, hence I am hesitant to use it in papers.

Comment: Papers don't ask for your birth certificate.

Comment: Yes, but employers will, and then there would be a disparity between the names on the documents and on papers. This was my main concern.

Comment: For legal purposes, universities do not care what name you publish on. The people who check your documents are not scientists and do not look up your papers.

Comment: If you edit to something like 'Will a mismatch between my papers and my documents give me trouble getting hired?" I'll retract my CV and edit; but you should also add a country tag

Comment: Thanks, that is a good edit suggestion. I will edit the question. And thanks for the help.